# How to wrap lines on hotkey but not automatically?

Tags: neovim, wrapping

**A bit of context:** I'm trying to use NeoVim after Spacemacs. In Spacemacs, there is `gql` key combination that hard wraps current long line of text into multiple short lines. It is useful if I want to write a long documentation comment. So I write a single line and let the IDE figure out linebreaks.

When I'm trying to configure NeoVim to wrap lines. And I want to achieve the following behaviour:

1. Don't wrap lines automatically when reaching a specific limit (like 80 columns).
2. Wrap line (ideally preserving indentation) with some hotkey like `gql`.

I tried `:set tw=80` and I can wrap lines by `gqq`, but they are also wrapped automatically...

How can I configure my NeoVim environment to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:set fo-=tc
```

You can set [`'formatoptions'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27formatoptions%27) with your preferences controlling when and how to format text.

See [`:help fo-table`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#fo-table) for the list of supported values in this option.

In particular, you'll want to remove these two:

> `t`: Auto-wrap text using `'textwidth'`
>
> `c`: Auto-wrap comments using `'textwidth'`, inserting the current comment leader automatically.

So, to remove them:

```
set formatoptions-=tc
```

Or the short abbreviated form at the beginning of the answer.

You'll probably want to make sure you're preserving this one, applicable to comments specifically:

> `q`: Allow formatting of comments with `gq`.

It's typically included in the default (which is `tcq`), so usually you don't need any action to keep it.

See also:

- The [`'comments'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27comments%27) option.
- The full [`fo-table`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#fo-table) for more useful options related to formatting and breaking lines.